# HTML / JS countdown to call on php file

Tags: javascript, php, html

good day! i'm using this code i found in this site to run a countdown timer that when it reaches zero, it will run a php file. what i have noticed is that when the tab on the server is closed is that it does not actually call the php file. do you guys have any solution to this? Any help will be very much appreciated.

switch1.js file and index.html file

```js
var interval;

function start() {
  // If a timer is already running, stop it
  stop();

  // Get and validate user input
  var userInput = document.getElementById('userTime').value;
  if (userInput.length == 0) {
    return alert("Please enter a value");
  }
  var numericExpression = /^[0-9]+$/
  if (!userInput.match(numericExpression)) {
    return alert("Please enter a number");
  }

  // Calculate end date/time
  expires = Date.now() + ((userInput * 60000) + 1000); // Assumes userInput is in seconds
  localStorage.setItem("expires", expires);
  runTimer(); // Start the actual timer
}

function stop() {
  if (interval) {
    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = null;
  }
  expires = 0;
  localStorage.setItem("expires", expires);

  // Clear the display
  display("notifier", " ");
}

var actions = {
  10: function() {
    display("notifier", "Just 10 seconds to go");
  },
  5: function() {
    display("notifier", "5 seconds left");
  },
  0: function() {
    window.location = 'off1.php'
  }
};

function runTimer() {
  interval = setInterval(function() {
    var remain = Math.floor((expires - Date.now()) / 1000);

    // If expired time come and gone
    if (remain < 0) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      interval = null;
      return;
    }

    display("countdown", toMinuteAndSecond(remain));
    actions[remain] && actions[remain]();
  }, 1000);
}

function display(notifier, str) {
  document.getElementById(notifier).innerHTML = str;
}

function toMinuteAndSecond(x) {
  return Math.floor(x / 60) + ":" + x % 60;
}

// If a timer is already setup (page has been refreshed) continue it
var expires = localStorage.getItem("expires");
if (expires > 0) runTimer();
```

```html
<div>
  <br>
  <br>
  </br>
  <div id="countdown"></div>
  <div id="notifier"></div>
  Please Enter A Number: <input type="text" id="userTime" />
  <input type="button" value="Go" onclick="start()" />
  <input type="button" onclick="stop()" value="Stop it" />
  </br>
</div>

<div>
  <br>
  <br>
  </br>
  <div id="countdown1"></div>
  <div id="notifier1"></div>
  Please Enter A Number: <input type="text" id="userTime1" />
  <input type="button" value="Go" onclick="start1()" />
  <input type="button" onclick="stop1()" value="Stop it" />
  </br>
</div>

<div>
  <br>
  <br>
  </br>
  <div id="countdown2"></div>
  <div id="notifier2"></div>
  Please Enter A Number: <input type="text" id="userTime2" />
  <input type="button" value="Go" onclick="start2()" />
  <input type="button" onclick="stop2()" value="Stop it" />
  </br>
</div>

<div>
  <br>
  <br>
  </br>
  <div id="countdown3"></div>
  <div id="notifier3"></div>
  Please Enter A Number: <input type="text" id="userTime3" />
  <input type="button" value="Go" onclick="start3()" />
  <input type="button" onclick="stop3()" value="Stop it" />
  </br>
</div>

<div>
  <br>
  <br>
  </br>
  <div id="countdown4"></div>
  <div id="notifier4"></div>
  Please Enter A Number: <input type="text" id="userTime4" />
  <input type="button" value="Go" onclick="start4()" />
  <input type="button" onclick="stop4()" value="Stop it" />
  </br>
</div>

<div>
  <br>
  <br>
  </br>
  <div id="countdown5"></div>
  <div id="notifier5"></div>
  Please Enter A Number: <input type="text" id="userTime5" />
  <input type="button" value="Go" onclick="start5()" />
  <input type="button" onclick="stop5()" value="Stop it" />
  </br>
</div>

<div>
  <br>
  </br>
  <br>
  <div id="countdown6"></div>
  <div id="notifier6"></div>
  Please Enter A Number: <input type="text" id="userTime6" />
  <input type="button" value="Go" onclick="start6()" />
  <input type="button" onclick="stop6()" value="Stop it" />
  </br>
</div>

<div>
  <br>
  <br>
  </br>
  <div id="countdown7"></div>
  <div id="notifier7"></div>
  Please Enter A Number: <input type="text" id="userTime7" />
  <input type="button" value="Go" onclick="start7()" />
  <input type="button" onclick="stop7()" value="Stop it" />
  </br>
</div>
```

Comment: The tag `<br>` is a line break no need to close it like `</br>`, it is enough to itself.

Comment: _"when the tab on the server is closed"_ - what to you mean with that? What _tab on the server_?

Comment: When you say "the tab", do you mean when the page is closed in the browswer? Of course it won't call the PHP file then. Closing the page/tab/browser will stop the execution of your js.

Comment: thank you! im sorry for that im still trying to understand html

Comment: "_...when the tab on the server is closed..._" Tabs are in browsers, not servers. Simple solution would be to not close the tab...

Comment: yes when the page is closed, it does not actually call the php file, do you have any idea on how to do it properly?

Comment: You need to give us way more background. Why would you want to execute the PHP file (and what does the file actually do?) if the user decides to close the tab?

Comment: actually, what im doing is im trying to close a certain appliance using the said server on a raspberry pi. what im trying to call is a php file that calls a python code that will control the relay

Answer (score 0):

You are running a javascript script on the client-side. The browser the user's computer are basically doing everything. When the counter running on the browser reaches zero it tells the browser to navigate to a certain link. The browser sends a GET request to that link.

On the server-side, a php script is initiated when the server receives a GET request to it.

Since when you are closing the tab, you are stopping the script, the event in which the GET request is being sent never occurs. Thus the server never gets this request and never starts the script.